Introspection and UserInfo Endpoint of KeyCloak server- Returning 401 unauthorized
I am trying to add a wrapper function over /openid-connect/token/introspect endpoint and openid-connect/token/userinfo.
I tried with the validate the token by passing the token in the body of the request:
Form formData = new Form();
formData.param("client_id", clientID);
formData.param("client_secret", clientSecret);
formData.param("token_type_hint", "requesting_party_token");
formData.param("token", token);

I am getting the access token from the below URL
/openid-connect/token.
I am using the same access token for validation but when I am calling the POST method on
/openid-connect/token/introspect URL, I am getting a 401 unauthorized response.
Similarly when I am sending a get request for openid-connect/token/userinfo and passing the the token in the header as below:
.header("Authorization", "Bearer " + accessToken)

I am getting a 401 unauthorized access.
I can see the scope present in the JWT token
Is there any configuration missing from keycloak. I have added a mapper also to map with the client:

I am getting the response is 401 unauthenticated.

You don't use the client_id/secret when using the token introspection endpoint, instead you provide the API's (protected resource) identity, and in the form of a basic authorization header.
Also, the token introspection is meant for the APIs to use, not the client application.
like this
 POST /introspect HTTP/1.1
 Host: server.example.com
 Accept: application/json
 Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
 Authorization: Basic czZCaGRSa3F0MzpnWDFmQmF0M2JW

 token=mF_9.B5f-4.1JqM&token_type_hint=access_token

See the documentation: OAuth 2.0 Token Introspection
it says

In OAuth 2.0 [RFC6749], the contents of tokens are opaque to
clients.    This means that the client does not need to know anything about the    content or structure of the token itself, if
there is any.  However,    there is still a large amount of metadata
that may be attached to a    token, such as its current validity,
approved scopes, and information    about the context in which the
token was issued.  These pieces of    information are often vital to
protected resources making    authorization decisions based on the tokens being presented.

You need to use the Basic authentication scheme to pass the id/secret. See the WikiPedia entry about it here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication
Also, in IdentityServer, we use a separate ID/secret for APIs (not the same as the client id/secret). Meaning the APIS, who are using the token introspection endpoint have a separate credentials, compared to the Client. The Token Introspection endpoint is not maent to be used by the client application.
